# How to remove the first part of a string in B

Tags: bash

I'd like to remove the first part of a string, here is the code, replacing the last part works, but not the fist part, any help? Thanks.

```
dir="/info/"
file_name="/info/test.db"

no_ext=${file_name%.db}
no_path=${no_ext%${dir}}

echo $file_name
echo $no_ext
echo $no_path
```

Comment: try `no_path=${no_ext#${dir}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same as with `%` (which removes suffix), you can use `#` which removes prefixes:

```
no_path="${file_name#${dir}}"
```

Arguably, you can just use a pattern here, because it seems to me like you're stripping the path off of a file name:

```
no_path="${file_name##*/}"
```

Double `#` makes the match greedy, so it removes everything up to the last slash. It's something I use all the time in my bash scripts' `Usage` functions: `echo "${o##*/} [-h] does something`

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you are trying to get the filename, filename without extension and extension.

Better user basename command to do this.

```
$ basename /Users/text/help1.txt
help1.txt

$ basename help1.txt| cut -d'.' -f2  
txt

$ basename help1.txt | cut -d'.' -f1
help1
```

Also if you would like to get the directory name without the filename
use dirname

```
$ dirname /Users/text/help1.txt
/Users/text
```